# How can I format a number to the fixed locale?

Tags: java, android

How can I insert to a string comma (,) after every 3 position starting from last?

```
input             desired output    

9876567846678     9,876,567,846,678  
567               567
1234              1,234
```

I used one method like first divide the whole string by three position and then while merging appending coma by three three position.

Is there any better solution? Is there function available to do this trick in java?

**Edit :**
LAS_VEGAS answer will format the number based on the locale.  But i want to format it to a fixed locale ...
how can i do tht?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a "trick" in Java:

```
public static String addCommas(int num) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
    return df.format(num);
}

System.out.println(addCommas(123456789));
```

**EDIT:**
In case you want your output to be independent from locale you can use the method below. It starts from the end so there is no need to reverse the string and should be quite efficient:

```
public static String addCommas(int num) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(num));
    for(int i = s.length() - 3; i > 0; i -= 3) {
        s.insert(i, ',');
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: will it take decimal format based on country? becoz it appending coma after 3 position in emulator(western number standard).. but in device it is appending 2 position(indian number standard).. How to change it to only one standard?

Comment: Isn't this a desired behaviour? So that a user from India sees those numbers in his own locale. What happens is that probably `Locale.US` is not supported by the Java runtime environment on the phone. So try `Locale.ROOT` and as a last resort try to use `Locale.UK`

Comment: @vnshetty - I agree with LAS_VEGAS, that's the **point** of a locale, and in general it's better to present users with data in a way that agrees with how they've set up their system.  Why do you think it's better for an Indian user to have to decipher Western-style groupings instead of their native expectations?

Comment: @ Andrzej Doyle @LAS_VEGAS its my requirement becoz im using voice to read those value. i have voice for only western style...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class, which is entirely used for formatting numbers as textual output.

In particular, an instance of `DecimalFormat` using the `,` symbol for separators is what you're looking for.  A format pattern of `#,##0` for example should output integers as you desire if you have no other constraints.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could also use a StringBuilder to do that. Here's a quickly hacked together solution:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("123456789");

        int initLength = sb.length();
        for(int i=1; i<initLength; i++){
            if(i % 3 == 0){
                sb.insert(initLength-i, ",");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
```