# How to format a number into standard currency format (comma seperated digits)

Tags: java, jquery, format, currency, number-formatting

I want to know how can i format a number like 2000000 into standard currency format i.e 2,000,000 using Java code or jQuery ?
Javacode is best but jQuery will also work
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format a number to the fixed locale?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035245/how-can-i-format-a-number-to-the-fixed-locale)

Comment: I need any builtin java or jQuery function so my work would be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery number formatter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/). Most formats are already there, and you can define your own.

Comment: thanks for helping i liked jQuery solution for it because i just have to display it that way. Server side formatted currency values are not required.
i had added jquery.numberformatter-1.2.2.js and used function in example on the page u referd, it is showing error that HashTable is not defined when i run the code. i had added jhashset.js but still geting error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062557/how-to-execute-javascipt-on-sproperty-struts-tag

can you please look into this

Answer (score 0):

Use NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(). Consider this:

```
int n = 2000000;

NumberFormat usa = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
NumberFormat uk = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
NumberFormat germany = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);

System.out.println(usa.format(n));
System.out.println(uk.format(n));
System.out.println(germany.format(n));
```

Comment: Thanks Opaco for help but i think jQuery solution will work better in my case. solution that Konerak provided got me issues that "HashTable is not defined" can u please help on that too ??

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Format currency to $0.00 format
 * @param  {[string]} price
 * @return {[string]} Formated Price
 */
util.formatCurrency = function(price) {
    return '$' + String(price).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
};
```