# how to execute javascript on <s:property> struts tag

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have `<s:property value="somevalue" id="someid">` feild. and i want to execute some scipt to format this value but don't know how to get any event to execute my script.
i want to do this

```
jQuery("#someid").load(function(){
 formatecurrency(this);
});

function formatecurrency(amount){
    jQuery("amount").parseNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
    jQuery("amount").formatNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
    alert(jQuery("#someid").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the property in a DOM element if you want to manipulate the DOM. The property tag simply renders a property value.

```
<span id="someid"><s:property .../></span>
```

Comment: @Rizstien ... I guess; updated answer. The point is that just rendering a value, like a string or a number, doesn't give you anything in the DOM. It's unclear what you're trying to do anyway, why not just use CSS?

Comment: <span id="someid">       <s:property value="Amount" />
</span> this is my feild and this is javascript code   jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("someid").parseNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
    jQuery("someid").formatNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
    alert(jQuery("someid").val());
  }); but in alert i get "undefined"

Comment: @Rizstien you've forgotten the "#". You also need to get tue value from it, not just try to format the DOM element. You know you can format numbers using JSP, right? Take a step back: you're just throwing code at a problem. You can't do it with CSS, you didn't say what you were trying to do in the question. Also, putting code in comments is illegible--edit the question.